actualizacion precio varias bases datos
buenas tardes
Para actualizar precios de la matriz a varias multi bases de datos como tipo sicar para tener la idea ya que serian tiendas. Alguna idea que tengo es realizar una aplicacion pero no se su aya otra forma de hacer algo o que ideas pueden darme gracias.

Para actualizar el precio en otra base de datos, puedes ejecutar el update con un dbLink, algo como:
SELECT dblink_connect('host=10.1.1.1
 user=user
 password=password
 dbname=oat');

SELECT dblink_exec('Update producto set precio=10 where idProducto = 30');

Si son varias bases de datos, haces el mismo procedimiento en cada una de las bases de datos.
